# Redirecting all versions of my old website to https version of my new website in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, forwarding

I am currently needing to redirect my old domain to my new domain. I setup forwarding on my old domain and everything redirects except for the https version. I just extended the ssl that is on my old domain and it still does not redirect. So now I am going to add a redirect using .htaccess instead of forwarding. I looked everywhere online but cant seem to find how to redirect all the versions of my old domain to the https version of my new domain in the .htaccess using rewrite method. This is all I found:

```
redirect permanent https://www.us.olddomain.com/ https://www.newdomain.us/
redirect permanent https://us.olddomain.com/ https://www.newdomain.us/
redirect permanent http://www.us.olddomain.com/ https://www.newdomain.us/
redirect permanent http://us.olddomain.com/ https://www.newdomain.us/
redirect permanent www.us.olddomain.com/ https://www.newdomain.us/
redirect permanent us.olddomain.com/ https://www.newdomain.us/
```

Is this not the method I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of posts for this already but you can do this on your old domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This would cause a redirection loop because both old and new domains are pointing at the same server. You must exclude the request that matches the new domain to prevent it.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I would have made the condition if he mentioned that they were on the same server. His post does not indicate that. Unless I can't read. :)

Comment: Yeah, OP hasn't mentioned it. I'll give you that :)

Comment: Thank you, yes, they are on the same server

Comment: Would this also work in the .htaccess on my new domain to force the www version?

Comment: @Ryan Not completely, every rule is made for each purpose. There needs to be more checks.

Comment: Ok, I disabled forwarding and setup this redirect in htaccess, the http version redirects, but the https version gives me a message that says This connection is Untrusted. It says my first domain uses an invalid security certificate and that this certificate is only valid for my new domain. But both SSL certs are valid. Also after going past the untrusted warning it shows my new website but has the old domain in the browser still? This is what I have in my htaccess:

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newdomain.us/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: That sounds like a configuration issue. You need to check your vhosts and make sure everything is pointing to the right locations in the apache config. You need to make sure old domain is point to the correct SSL certs, the correct document root and server name is for old domain. That really isn't an htaccess issue because ssl is checked before any mod rewrite is performed.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with my ssl, it is now working properly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex pattern to catch all of your old domains and redirect as follows

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?us\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
Redirect ^ https://www.newdomain.us%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above rule checks for `us.olddomain.com` (with or without `www` prefix) and redirects to the new `https` site URL. Since, it doesn't matter whether the old URL was accessed via `http` or `https` and the redirection is still required, the rule doesn't check for it.